# clock_gettime API is giving negative values

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, timestamp

I want current system time in micro seconds, so i have written a program using clock_gettime But it is returning negative values some times. Can someone help me on this.

```
int main(void) {
    struct timespec tms;

        /* The C11 way */
        /* if (! timespec_get(&tms, TIME_UTC)) { */

        /* POSIX.1-2008 way */
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&tms)) {
                    return -1;
             }
            /* seconds, multiplied with 1 million */
            long long micros = tms.tv_sec * 1000000;
                /* Add full microseconds */
                micros += tms.tv_nsec/1000;

                printf("Microseconds: %lld\n",micros);
                return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `%llu`?

Comment: Check the size of `time_t` (the type of `tv_sec`). It'll only be 32 bits if you're compiling for 32bit Linux.

Comment: And to expand on @Mat's accurate comment, you should write `1000000LL` to force the multiplication to be done as `long long`.  If `time_t` is a 32-bit type, the multiplication will be done as a 32-bit multiplication (with overflow), and the (overflowed) result will be converted to `long long` afterwards.

Comment: Ohh okay. I got it. it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @Devendar If you have found a solution please consider adding an answer to your question. This will contribute to StackOverflow which helped you in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

Hope the below code helps you:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<time.h>

    void get_time_in_ms()
    {
        long ms;
        time_t time;
        struct timespec spec;
        char tm[14];

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);

        time  = spec.tv_sec;
        ms = round(spec.tv_nsec / 1000000 ); // Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds

        printf("Current time: %lu.%03ld seconds since the Epoch\n", time, ms);
        sprintf(tm,"%lu%03ld",time, ms);
        printf("Time : %s\n", tm);
    }

    void main() {
            get_time_in_ms();
    }
```

Comment: The question is seeking a single number representing the number of microseconds since the epoch (and then printing the value to verify it).  This answer is providing the number of milliseconds since the epoch and is not giving it as a single number.